# Connecting two containers with different servers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect two docker containers with different servers. In Server A, I have my web application and for the Server B, My Database. How they can connect? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the port of database to some host port on Server B then from Server A hosting Webapp you can access the db using Server-b-ip:mapped-port.

Similarly for the web server you need to map port 80 and/or 443 on the Server A for it to be accessible.
See references [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

Comment: Thank you! Just like mapping from host to container?